# Getting the stored value of each variable

Tags: llvm

I read in another post that I couldn't get actual value for variables with unnamed identifiers. I need to get the variables with named identifier in instruction I with its actual value for example: 'int x =0;' I need to get that variable v has value 0. When I used ' I->getOperand(0)' I got that instruction itself or alloca instruction for some operations like sext.

Answer (score 0):

To read the variable name, have look inside `lli`. You would need to look inside the `ExecutionContext`, and how the interpreter is executed. Essentially the interpreter visits instructions as they are executed. Inside the visit functions, you can read the name of the variables.